# Change UILabel text then UIView redraw

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel

I have a UIView and this UIView is outside of screen. There is a UILabel on this UIView.

And an animation will move this UIView in.

But this UIView will auto move to outside of screen as I change the UIlabel text. Why??

This is code:

```
var count = 0
// move View in
@IBAction func click(sender: AnyObject) {
    let h = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height / 2

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.myView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h) ,
                size: self.myView.frame.size)
        }, completion: nil)
}
// Change text
@IBAction func setText(sender: AnyObject) {
    lbl.text = "\(count++)"
    // view will disappear
}
```

**Original screen**

[image: Original screen]

**View move in**

[image: View in move]

Comment: Did you set the constraint for label ?

Comment: Is the UIView contain UILabel or not?

Comment: UILabel is on UIView. UIView and UILabel will disappear after set label->text

Comment: @ManiaChamp yes, I set the constraint : center of uiview